# WordPress wp_head - how to remove link canonical and api?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.3

How can I remove these two links from the WP header?

```
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://xxx/wp-json/' />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://xxx/" />
```

I don't know what they are for. They just look redundant to me.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meta `rel="canonical"` is printed by `rel_canonical` function, plugged into `wp_head` action in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` (line 237 in WP 4.4), so

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
```

should do it.

For api (also plugged in that file, line 213) the code would be

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head' );
```

I don't know what the api meta means, but I'm quite sure that canonical should help you with SEO.

Comment: Thanks for the help!